# Why did Buddhism nearly become extinct in Sri Lanka?

Tags: history

I read when the British came to Sri Lanka (Ceylon) during the colonial era, Buddhism was virtually extinct in Sri Lanka and has degenerated into very low forms of superstition. However, because some Sri Lankans wanted to stop British Christianity, they requested the Burmese Sangha to reinstate a Sri Lankan monastic Sangha. I read some intellectual Sri Lankan laymen had debates with Christians, where both sides (logically) accused the other side of superstition.

Why did Buddhism become virtually extinct in Sri Lanka? Was that 'extinction' somehow related to the form of Buddhism or how it was practised, or something else?

Comment: Do you know that long before British came to Sri Lanka, the country was ruled by [Portugese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Ceylon) (1505-1658) and then [Dutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_Ceylon) (1640-1796)? Local people resisted these invasions and rebelled time to time against the rulers. Buddhist monks faced so much difficulties during these periods. Buddhism was very much fertile before these periods. Ruins of buddhist monasteries more than India can be found everywhere in Sri Lanka.

Comment: The link says: Portuguese rule was always in the maritime provinces and the people whom they converted were the coastal folk. They were the backbone of their power. Many of the princes they converted had either died or were no longer Catholic. The rest of Ceylon remained in the Buddhist-Hindu religion.

Comment: @Damith I don't think your comments are relevant to the question, of why it nearly became extinct. Or are you saying the answer is that it's because Buddhist monks faced difficulties during the three centuries of Portuguese and then Dutch rule? If so, would you please post that as an answer, not a comment?

Comment: @ChrisW Sorry sir! I will post these with a detailed answer (most probably within next few days). Until then you can either delete them or keep them.

Answer (score 3):

I have quoted 3 sources below on this topic.

Basically, it says that in Sri Lanka and other Theravada countries, people who lived over 150 years ago, thought that even stream entry was no longer possible because in-depth understanding of meditation had been forgotten. They felt that it's better to practise virtues and make merit, while waiting for the next Buddha, Meteyya or Maitreya to come and show them the path to Nibbana. Supposedly, even Buddhaghosa, who authored the Visuddhimagga around the 5th century CE in Sri Lanka, held this view.

However, Buddhist meditation practices (based on the Satipatthana Sutta and Visuddhimagga, as well as other suttas) started to be revived in Burma as a popular movement, over a hundred years ago, and then spread to other countries including Sri Lanka. This seemed to have reinvigorated the faith of Theravadins (both monks and lay people) in the possibility of stream entry and enlightenment.

Here, Buddhism did not become extinct in Sri Lanka, but people simply lost faith in the possibility of attaining even stream entry, until Buddhist meditation was reintroduced to them from Burma.

In the [Broken Buddha](http://www.buddhistische-gesellschaft-berlin.de/downloads/brokenbuddhanew.pdf) book, S. Dhammika wrote:

> In Sri Lanka it is widely believed that it is not possible to become
>   enlightened anymore and it’s not just simple folk who believe this
>   either. I once attended a talk by the famous Narada Thera of
>   Vajirarama in Colombo during which he said that it is  even 
>   impossible  to  become  a  sotapanna  today.  Richard  Gombrich  found
>   this  same  idea  to  be widely  held  in  Sri  Lanka.  ‘The 
>   comparative  rarity  of  meditation  is  closely  connected  with  the
>   widespread belief in the  decline of  Buddhism. A  village  girl said
>   that in a Buddha-less period one must  keep  trying,  but  only 
>   limited  progress  is  possible.  It  is  further  believed  by  the 
>   majority  of monks,  at  least  those  whose  general  attitudes  can 
>   be  described  as  traditional,  that  the  sasana  has already 
>   declined  so  far  that  it  is  no  longer  possible  for  men  to 
>   attain  nirvana.  This  opinion  is  very prevalent  among  the 
>   laity...One  monk  even  specified  that  till  (Metteyya)  comes  it 
>   is  not  even possible to become a sotapanna. The last arahat is
>   commonly said to have been Maliyadeva (1st cent B.C.E).  Others  say 
>   that  there may  still  be  human  arahats,  but  it  is  unlikely 
>   and/or undiscoverable ....
>
> I have heard these same views expressed a thousand times in Sri Lanka.
>   Even Buddhaghosa did not really believe that Theravada practice could
>   lead to Nirvana. His Visuddhimagga is supposed to be a detailed,  step
>   by  step  guide  to  enlightenment.  And yet  in  the  postscript  he 
>   says  he  hopes  that  the merit  he  has  earned  by  writing  the
>   Visuddhimagga  will  allow  him  to  be  reborn  in  heaven,  abide
>   there  until  Metteyya  appears,  hear  his  teaching  and  then 
>   attain  enlightenment.

In [Encyclopedia of Buddhism](http://www.ahandfulofleaves.org/documents/encyclopedia%20of%20buddhism_2%20vols_%20buswell.pdf) (editor: Robert E. Buswell, Jr.), it is written:

> By the tenth century C.E., vipassana meditation appears to have fallen
>   out of practice in the Therevada school. By that time it was commonly
>   believed that the religion of Gautama Buddha had so declined that
>   liberation  through  insight  could no longer  be  attained until the
>   advent of the future Buddha Metteyya (Sanskrit,  Maitreya)  many  eons
>   from  now.  In  the  early eighteenth  century,  however,  renewed 
>   interest  in  the Satipatthana Sutta (Discourse on the Foundations of
>   Mindfulness)  led  to  a  revival  of  vipassana meditation in Burma
>   (Myanmar). After encountering initial resistance,  the  practice  of 
>   vipassana was  endorsed  by  the Burmese sangha and embraced by the
>   royal court.
>
> By the late nineteenth century, a distinct praxis and organizational 
>   pattern  had  emerged  that  set  the  stage  for the modern vipassana
>   movement of the twentieth century.  Led  chiefly  by  reform  minded 
>   scholar-monks,  a variety  of  simplified  meditation  techniques 
>   were  devised based on readings of the Satipatthana Sutta, the
>   Visuddhimagga (Path to Purification), and related texts. These 
>   techniques  typically  follow  the  method  of  bare insight.
>
> The 
>   teaching  of  vipassana also  prompted  the development   of   new
>   Buddhist   institutions   called wipathana  yeikthaor  insight 
>   hermitages.  Initially  attached to monasteries, these evolved into
>   independent lay oriented meditation centers. A related development was
>   the rise of personality cults devoted to the veneration of 
>   prominent   meditation   teachers   as   living arhats. In terms of
>   impact, the popularization of vipassana represents  the  most 
>   significant  development  in Burmese Buddhism in the twentieth
>   century.
>
> Thailand has also witnessed a revival of vipassana practice in the
>   modern  period,  and  both  Burmese  and  Thai  meditation  teachers 
>   have  been  instrumental  in  propagating vipassana in Sri Lanka,
>   India, and the West.

In [Meditation en Masse](https://tricycle.org/magazine/meditation-en-masse/), Erik Braun wrote:

> These days many assume that Buddhism and meditation go hand in hand -
>   sometimes they are even considered to be one and the same. But even
>   counting Theravadins, progenitors of the massively popular insight
>   meditation (Vipassana) movement, relatively few Buddhists historically
>   have ever understood meditation to be essential. On the contrary,
>   instead of meditating, the majority of Theravadins and dedicated
>   Buddhists of other traditions, including monks and nuns, have focused
>   on cultivating moral behavior, preserving the Buddha’s teachings
>   (dharma), and acquiring the good karma that comes from generous
>   giving. To be sure, such folks have recognized the critical role
>   meditation plays in awakening—in the Theravada view, you cannot become
>   enlightened without such practice—but they have not doubted that one
>   can live a worthwhile and authentic Buddhist life without meditating.
>   Aiming not toward awakening but toward a good rebirth, many
>   Theravadins have even argued that meditation is inappropriate in our
>   degenerate age, except perhaps for a rare few living in the isolation
>   of jungles or mountain caves. Where, then, did this now pervasive idea
>   come from that meditation lies at the heart of Buddhist life?
>
> This question brings us to Burma just over a century ago. Prior to
>   this time, no trend toward widespread meditation had developed
>   anywhere. It is true that Thai forest masters, above all Ajaan Mun
>   (1870–1949) and revivalist figures in Sri Lanka such as Dharmapala
>   (1864–1933), played an important part in the establishment of insight
>   practice and sounded the call for lay meditation. But they did not
>   spark any broad-based movements. One must look instead to Burma to
>   account for the ascendance of meditation to a popular
>   practice—specifically, that of insight meditation. The Vipassana view
>   understood meditation as the logical and even necessary application of
>   a Buddhist perspective to one’s life, whether lay or monastic. The
>   rise of this practice, however, was not strictly an indigenous
>   development. It came into being specifically through colonial
>   influence. (In fact, no current tradition of insight practice can
>   reliably trace its history back further than the late 19th or early
>   20th century.) Though now a global movement, insight practice had its
>   start in a moment of interaction between a Western empire and an
>   Eastern dynasty. Indeed, one could go so far as to pinpoint its
>   origins to a particular day: November 28, 1885, when the British
>   Imperial Army conquered the Buddhist kingdom of Burma.